# How to generate QR code in PHP with custom fields

Tags: php, kohana, qr-code

I want to add these fields in QR code "First Name", "Last Name","Phone" , "Email", "Homepage URL".

I am using **[qrcode](http://code-snippets.co.cc)** class which uses Google API to generate the QR code.

```
public function contact_info_custom($fname,$lname, $phone, $email,$url){
    $this->data = "MECARD:N:".$lname.";".$fname.";FN:".$fname.' '.$lname.";TEL:".$phone.";EMAIL:".$email.";URL:".$url.";";
    
}
```

So the problem is: ***Last Name* & *Website*  fields not appearing on phone**

The QR code generated by above method is [image: here]

Comment: Have you an example QR code that isn't working for you?

Comment: http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chld=L|0&chl=MECARD%3AN%3AMimrot%3BNandkishor%3BFN%3ANandkishor+Mimrot%3BTEL%3A123456789%3BEMAIL%3An.mimrot%40somethin.com%3BURL%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fchat.stackoverflow.com%2Fusers%2F3382993%2Fnand%3B

Comment: Since a QR code just encodes some text, this has nothing to do with PHP, or Kohana, or Google, and is instead a question about the "mecard" format which you are encoding.

Comment: This online decoder picks up the URL but not the first name: http://zxing.org/w/decode?u=http%3A%2F%2Fchart.apis.google.com%2Fchart%3Fchs%3D200x200%26cht%3Dqr%26chld%3DL%257C0%26chl%3DMECARD%253aN%253aMimrot%3BNandkishor%3BFN%253aNandkishor%2520Mimrot%3BTEL%3A123456789%3BEMAIL%253an.mimrot%40somethin.com%3BURL%253ahttp%3A%2F%2Fchat.stackoverflow.com%2Fusers%2F3382993%2Fnand%3B I notice all the fields except the first name are formatted as `KEY:VALUE;` Seems like that field is missing its key.

Comment: @IMSoP Would you like to suggest the Key names for Last name and Website field? I have tried with various keys here but not succeded

Comment: I know nothing about this format, I was just pointing out that you are looking in the wrong place by trying to debug your PHP code; the QR code is faithfully representing the text you gave it, it's just not having the effect you want in some unspecified reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going form [this documentation](http://theqrplace.wordpress.com/2011/05/02/qr-code-tech-info-mecard-format/), some of your delimiters aren't quite right, so:

```
$this->data = "MECARD:N:".$lname.";".$fname.";FN:".$fname.' '.$lname.";TEL:".$phone.";EMAIL:".$email.";URL:".$url.";";
```

Becomes more like:

```
$this->data = "MECARD:N:".$lname.",".$fname.";NICKNAME:".$fname.' '.$lname.";TEL:".$phone.";EMAIL:".$email.";URL:".$url.";";
```

Giving:
[image]

Which then scans correctly, at least on a Windows Phone using Bing Vision.

Comment: I am not getting **Website** field on Samsung GT15110

Comment: That might be a limitation of your QR reader software -- I've tested with a Windows Phone, and it reads it OK